# unexpected identifier with scrolling menù

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with my first html website. I'm trying to create a vertical scrolling menù, and this is my code:

```
<body onLoad="javascript:startmenu()">
<div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" /></a>       
        </div>      
        <ul>
            <li class="selected"><a href="index.html"><span>home</span></a></li>
            <li><a onMouseOver="javaScript:menufunc()"><span>prodotti</span></a></li>
                <li>
                <div id="prod">
                    <ul>
                    <li> - <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a><br> </li>
                    <li> - <a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>Yahoo</a><br> </li>
                    <li> - <a href='http://www.altavista.com'>AltaVista</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html"><span>contatti</span></a></li>   
            <li><a href="about.html"><span>dove siamo</span></a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="services.html"><span>services</span></a></li> -->     
        </ul>
</div>
```

and this is the function:

```
function startmenu(){
document.getElementById('prod').style.display = "none"; }

function menufunc(){
if(document.getElementById().style.display == "none"){
    document.getElementById().style.display = "block";
} else{
    startmenu();
} }
```

but I recive this error: Uncaught TypeError: *Cannot read property 'style' of null: [Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier]*

Comment: You have to write the ID of the element you want to get!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the ID of the element you want to get.like:

```
if(document.getElementById('prod').style.display == "none"){
     document.getElementById('prod').style.display = "block";
```